# How to create a instance of Set<?> in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, set, mockito, stubbing

I am writing a unit test where I am stubbing various classes and at one stage I need to return an instance of Set as the value. How do I create the instance with inserting values in to it. Below is what I have tried and getting compilation error

```
private Set<?> keys;
String[] keys1 = new String[2];
keys1[0] =  "filter1";
keys1[1] = "filter2";
keys = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(keys1));

when(ctx.getFilter()).thenReturn(keys);
```

Comment: What is the return type of `getFIlter()` and what is the compilation error that you get?

Comment: Below is the compilation error:

java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method thenReturn(Set<capture#2-of ?>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Set<capture#2-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (Set<capture#3-of ?>)

Answer (score 3):

`Set<?>` really means "it's a set of objects of some type, but I don't know which type in particular." In cases when it does not matter you could make it a set of any type that you would like - for instance, in your case you are making a set of strings:

```
String[] keys1 = new String[2];
keys1[0] =  "filter1";
keys1[1] = "filter2";
keys = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(keys1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have this in a test method. At least one error is that you should not declare your local variable `keys` as `private`.

Another problem you might have is the return type of `ctx.getFilter()`, which you don't give in your question. But it must match the type of `keys`. The type `Set<?>` which means a set of any type is not that common as a return type, because it is unknown what the type of the contents is, so you can not do very much with the contents without casting.

The following should work:

```
Set<?> keys;
String[] keys1 = new String[2];
keys1[0] =  "filter1";
keys1[1] = "filter2";
keys = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(keys1));

when(ctx.getFilter()).thenReturn(keys);
```

Comment: Keys are global variable and it has been declared outside the function at class level.  It obvious when I am trying to return an instance of Set<?> then the return type would be Set<?> and I don't see how your solution is different than mine other changing the access of keys which is not the working